# With ifelse can I create range and have a blank output if if it's false so I can create another ifelse

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have coordinate in 2 different vectors named x and y. I want to create a third variable telling in which cadran (quarter) they are. With my ifelse statement I cannot figure out to use a range as an example x would be 25>x>0 and 25>y>0 instead of just being x>0 & y>0 . Also because I want to create this variable with multiple cadran I would like to have multiple ifelse statement that does not erase each others. so at the end my third column gives me the cadran for each of these pair of x and y

Here is my code so far and I am kind of block here

```
library(dplyr)

x <- c(3,-2, 35, -4, 34, 20, 45)
y <- c(0, 2, 33, -4, 50, 30, 10)

df <- cbind.data.frame(x, y)
df

#Creating  a third variable reacting to coordinate
df$quart <-ifelse(df$x>0 & df$y>0, "quart1", NA)
df$quart <-ifelse(df$x<0 & df$y<0, "quart2", NA)
df
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: There are [`case_when`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) from the `dplyr` package and [`fcase`](https://rdrr.io/github/Rdatatable/data.table/man/fcase.html) from `data.table` - you might find this useful.

Comment: Case_when does a great job thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Simple approach

You can use multiple `ifelse()` in the same conjunction, it may seem difficult to overview in the beginning, but using indentation styles which makes sense to you, could get you some of the way.

```
#Creating  a third variable reacting to coordinate

df$quart <- ifelse(
  df$x<0 & df$y<0,
  "quart3",
  ifelse(
    df$x<25 & df$y<25,
    "quart2",
    ifelse(
      df$x<50 & df$y<50,
      "quart1",
      "other"
    )
  )  
)
```

Note that with this approach, quart = "other" if X and Y are equal to 0, or 25, or 50, or >50. Consider the use of `<=` instead of `<`.

## Improved readability

I suggest that you utilize `dplyr`, for easier readability.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  x = c(3,-2, 35, -4, 34, 20, 45),
  y = c(0, 2, 33, -4, 50, 30, 10)
)

df <- mutate(
  df,
  quart = ifelse(
    x < 0 & y < 0,
    "quart3",
    ifelse(
      x < 25 & y < 25,
      "quart2",
      ifelse(
        x < 50 & y < 50,
        "quart1",
        "other"
      )
    )  
  )
)
```

The strength in using mutate is that it is really easy to navigate you variables (columns), as each row is handled independently, instead of handling the entire x and y vectors. This makes a difference, if you need to use functions which doesn't handle vectors with more than a single value.

After reading OP comment and OP answer, I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you. However, I would like to create  more cadran and have "quart1" with x being between 50 and 25 (50>x>25) and same for y is that possible ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question! I have now updated my answer based on your comment and your answer. Please let me know if I interpreted your intentions correctly or wrongly!

Comment: Both way works now for my problem. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Using case_when ended up being the easiest way of doing for me. Thank you for your comments/solutions

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(3,-2, 35, -4, 34, 20, 45),
  y = c(0, 2, 33, -4, 50, 30, 10)
)

df

df %>% 
  mutate(category = case_when(
    x > 25 & y >25   ~ "q1",
    x > 0 & y > 0   ~ "q2",
    x < 0 & y < 0 ~ "q3", 
    TRUE ~ "other"
  )
  )
```